# Should the existence of flag outcomes / responses be made more obvious

Tags: feature-request, flags, flag-history

I had been a member of Stack Overflow for nearly 3 years, thinking that flags were just "fire and forget" to improve the site. I had *no idea* that there were responses to my flags, let alone that I could see a list of them. *(So I hereby apologise for appearing not to learn from some of the responses.)* I didn't think there was a way of getting to them, because "flags" is not an option in the list of tabs: "summary" / "answers" / "questions" / "tags" / "badges" / "favorites" / "bounties" / "reputation" / "all actions" / "responses" / "votes".

- The thing that you have to click on to get to them (in the "IMPACT" area of the Activity tab of the user's page) doesn't even look like it's clickable unless you hover over it.
- The styling is very similar to other items on the same page which are not clickable.
- The wording on it makes it look like it's just a piece of information, and even then, the wording implies that the link is only related to "helpful" flags

But it *is* clickable, and the page it takes you to is about *all* of your flags (not just the helpful ones), and includes the responses.

Does more thought need to be applied to the UI design in this area to make it clearer? Maybe this should be on a "flags" tab to make its existence more obvious. (Maybe there is a way of finding out what percentage of users who have created flags, but have never visited that page on their own profile?)

Comment: Definitely. I've seen a few re-flags from the new users regarding things which were already informed in a flag reply.

Comment: Not actually fire-and-forget, when you get it wrong you do get a flagging ban.  Not getting it wrong is nothing to worry about.  A fair number of users know about that link and shouldn't, not the kind of thing to be a perfectionist about.

Comment: I've been ranting about the poor discoverability of flag responses for years.

Comment: Very much this. I remember I started to understand the correct flag intent and the way they were handled  *after* doing lots of flagging / triage / LQA reviews, and then, some day, I browsed my history and realizing some of the flags were declined. At this point I digged more in meta, but maybe I would still be flagging incorrectly if I had not looked at the my flag history.

Comment: This is also [complained about over at Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290061/282094) specific to < 15 Rep. sees nothing, even if they dig.

Comment: I assumed the lack of notifications was because the moderators/SO didn't want to deal with people disagreeing with rejected flags. I'm actually very interested in the responses to my flags, but I almost never think to go look them up after the fact.

Answer (score 59):

It actually goes further than that:

- To even *see* your flag summary, you have to know that the "X helpful flags" link in your profile is clickable
- The sorting options in the flag summary are terrible. You can't sort by keywords, can't sort by time handled, can't sort by specific flag types.
- If your flags get handled out of order (they always do), then you have to hover over the time next to the flag response message (!) to get the exact time when it was handled. This is terrible if you have more than a couple.

As a result the option to follow up on flags is really, really obtuse when it doesn't need to be. If I want to see any messages on my helpful custom flags for the month, guess what? I have to manually dig through all of my helpful post flags to find them. It's not a very efficient UI.

For the normal non meta user, the only time when you're actually informed of the existance of the flag summary is when you're close to a flag ban, why?

Comment: And if you flag infrequently enough to never be considered for a flag ban, it doesn't matter even if every single one of your flags gets declined, [you will never find out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261760/users-with-100-flag-decline-rates-will-never-know-their-flags-are-being-decline).

Comment: @BoltClock I like peterj's suggestion there. If a moderator specifies a custom text as flag response, it should show up like a comment ping in the inbox. I'd really like that.

Comment: I have flagged only 4 things and had no idea that was clickable, even though I try to read up on meta every once in a while. I had just assumed that a lot of that data was unlocked once you got more rep.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to making the location of my flags more obvious and user-friendly I think it would be beneficial to get an Inbox notification when a flag receives a response.

Comment: Only if it can be turned off. I flag quite a bit, and don't want a notification for every single one.

Comment: @jhpratt: What about being notified when your flag is rejected only? After all if it's rejected something went wrong...

Comment: Notification only on declined (maybe even disputed) flags seems like a fair compromise, since if you're getting enough of those to be bothered by it you're doing something wrong and need to either fix it or stop flagging anyway.