# Why can't I flag a question on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, bug, flags

I am trying to flag a question as a duplicate. When I click on the flag link, a new dialog box appears and I can enter the question (or question id) there.

But after clicking the flag post button (flag submission button) nothing happens.

Comment: Since you're talking about entering question IDs, I'm assuming you're trying to flag a question as a duplicate? If so, your flag from 16 hours ago *did* work, it just takes some time for the community to get to it.

Comment: You can view status of your flags in your profile... What did you expect to happen?

Comment: No i can see anything out there

Comment: You can see the outcomes of your flags [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/6562458) (This link is only clickable by you and moderators) @Sumithran

Comment: @Magisch I would consider that an answer. And a helpful one aon top.

Comment: @Magisch I can also click on that link. Does that make me a moderator?

Comment: @AndréKool I was imprecise in my formulation. This link only displays a flag summary for OP and moderators. For others, it leads to 404 page not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you do not have sufficient reputation to vote to close directly, you need to rely on standard flags to indicate a post should be closed. When you cast such a flag, it submits the post for review in the Close Votes review queue. From there, reviewers can vote to close (causing your flag to be accepted) or vote to leave a post open (causing your flag to be declined).

You are not directly notified of the results of your flags, and due to the size of the Close Votes queue it may take a while for them to be acted on. You can view the status of pending or reviewed flags in your profile by clicking on the "XX helpful flags" text (which goes to [the page Magisch linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/6562458)). I see two pending duplicate flags in there, so they were registered with the system.

Better systems for surfacing flags and their results [have been proposed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370696/should-the-existence-of-flag-outcomes-responses-be-made-more-obvious) ([several times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284688/notify-me-when-my-flag-has-been-handled), actually).

Comment: IIRC, automatic declines only happen if the review consensus is unanimous against the flags, right? Otherwise they become disputed.