# Add a small notification about declined flags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, declined-flags, flag-history

It's difficult to notice when you have a flag declined. You can do it in two ways:

1. You click on the list of flags and you notice the red text. Not trivial in case you raise a lot of flags (you may need to scroll and it's easy to miss it)
2. You get the notification when raising a new flag. I think this will trigger only when having a lot of declined flags (I don't know the exact rules).

What I suggest is a small red icon that gets added to notify us that we have a declined flag:

> [image]

The icon is added when a flag is declined and removed when we click to see the list of flags, as simple as that. No notification or custom message or [complex feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284688/8620333). It can even be similar to the red dots we get for the review queues.

> [image]

This will help us to keep track of flags and won't require a lot of development.

Comment: Frankly, I'm a little surprised this isn't already a feature. I'm more surprised that no one has brought it up before, this looks quite useful.

Comment: It is a feature.  If you flag something for a reason and that flag is then declined, you'll get a little warning asking you to review your declined flags.

Comment: @Makoto you only get it when you try to raise another flag (my point (2)) or maybe there is another notification somewhere else?

Comment: I was told that the reason this isn't implemented already is that: We don't want more meta posts about declined flags! But.. just go to your flag list, and click on the declined. If you're a paranoid flagger, you'll know exactly how many declined flags you have at all times :P

Comment: @Scratte well, I am lazy person ;) I want a clear indication.

Comment: Gah! No! There's already so much angst over declined flags, I'd rather just *remove* the notification...

Comment: This looks like it can be solved with [a userscript](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/DeclinedFlagsNotifier.user.js). Oh wait...

Comment: @SamuelLiew add it as an answer then ;) but I prefer an effort from the SO team :p

Comment: @SamuelLiew like it, but there is a way to reset the icon after you have looked at the list of declined flags?

Comment: @Steve no, because the list of flags does not have unique ids, so we can't track which ones have been viewed.

Comment: @TemaniAfif if lots of people start using this userscript, I guarantee the SO team will be likely to implement it because it calls four additional pages per page load.

Comment: @SamuelLiew thanks, I have found a compromise. I have changed the _const recent_ to show just one month back (0.083). That's enough to keep the number low or empty for my flag history

Comment: How would this alert be cleared? Clicking on it? Going to the flags page and hovering over each individual declined flag?

Comment: @TylerH by simply click on the link to see the flags page

Comment: @SamuelLiew well then, the answer box is below :) let's promote your script since the question is a Hot Meta one ;)

Comment: If the most recent flag you've raised is declined, then you see a warning in the flag dialog. Similar post [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396809).

Comment: @double-beep yes I know (this is my point (2)). Not very useful IMO because we need another action to notice the notification

Comment: I think it's important to notify people of declined flags, it is the only way one can learn when and how to properly flag. The current notification doesn't work: One can fall several things, one gets declined but later another gets accepted, and I'll never know about the declined flag unless I look at the page listing all the flags ([which is well hidden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319396)).

Comment: Another related post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370696/7328782

Comment: More: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228267/show-declined-flags-in-inbox https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230877/sending-a-notification-when-a-flag-is-reviewed

Answer (score 40):

I've created a userscript that fetches the four different types of declined flags in the past three days and display it in an inbox-style dropdown in the topbar.

[image]

#### [DeclinedFlagsNotifier](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/DeclinedFlagsNotifier.user.js)

Comment: Can you put it in Stack Apps?

Comment: Just a heads up, this script caused me to briefly hit the [loading page rate limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide/164900#loading-pages) on SE when I was quickly navigating around a user profile. (The exact quote I got back from support regarding the limit was: "There appear to be a very large number of requests going to /users/flag-summary/ which is likely what triggered the rate limit. We are sometimes seeing up to a dozen requests to the flag summary page all within a second or two.")

Comment: @zcoop98 See my comment above: "*if lots of people start using this userscript, I guarantee the SO team will be likely to implement it because it calls four additional pages per page load.*" - thanks for doing your part.

Answer (score 9):

I was going to disagree because I thought it would make even more work for the moderators with people challenging the declined flags all the time, but then I went and looked at my own declined flags:

[image: Declined flag message]

I had no idea I wasn't supposed to do that. I still wouldn't have known if I hadn't read this post today.

So, I agree that we need a notification for declined flags. I've been using SO for a few years and there are still things I don't know about the site. How much more is that true for new users?

Comment: Relevant: [What is the correct procedure for handling large amounts of trashy comments on a post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322702/11682469)

Comment: It still won't be clear that you're supposed to do that, unfortunately. The moderator team is apparently split on whether you should flag individual comments or flag the whole post. I'd prefer flagging the whole post if you want a large number of comments deleted. I guess some of my colleagues disagree with me. I think that's bananas.